# Learning Haskell: string transformations

Tags: haskell

Knowing little about string manipulation libraries I wanted to write these simple transformations in Haskell myself. I was suprised how much boilerplate I was able to produce. How can I simplify it? Would using regex produce most readable code?

Desired output:

```
*Main> prettyCamel "foo-bar-example"
"fooBarExample"
*Main> prettyCapitals "foo-bar-example"
"FooBarExample"
```

Code:

```
import Data.Char

prettyCapitals = foldr1 (++) . (map capitalize) . splitString
prettyCamel = foldr1 (++) . camelCase . splitString

capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : xs

camelCase [] = []
camelCase (x:xs) = x : (map capitalize xs)

splitString :: String -> [String]
splitString = foldr (splittingAdd (== '-')) []

splittingAdd splitPredicate char words = 
 if splitPredicate char
  then "":words
  else (char : headOrEmpty words) : tailOrEmpty words

headOrEmpty [] = ""
headOrEmpty (x:xs) = x

tailOrEmpty [] = []
tailOrEmpty (x:xs) = xs
```

Comment: Regex is not at all idiomatic code for haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using plain old recursion?

```
prettyCamel ""         =  ""
prettyCamel ('-':c:s)  =  toUpper c : prettyCamel s
prettyCamel (c:s)      =  c : prettyCamel s

prettyCapitals (c:s)   =  toUpper c : prettyCamel s
```

Alternatively, you can get a point-free version of one of the functions with the `Data.List.Split` package.

```
prettyCapitals  =  concatMap capitalize . splitOn "-"
prettyCamel s   =  x : prettyCapitals xs
  where (x:xs)  =  splitOn "-" s
```

(Using your previous definition of `capitalize`.)

Comment: Pattern matching is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use libraries and composition!

```
import Data.Char       (toUpper)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

capitalize (c:cs) = toUpper c : cs

prettyCaps = concatMap capitalize . splitOn "-"

prettyCamel s = let (w:ws) = splitOn "-" s in w ++ concatMap capitalize ws
```

Works as expected:

```
>> prettyCaps "foo-bar-example"
FooBarExample
>> prettyCamel "foo-bar-example"
fooBarExample
```

Answer (score 1):

`foldr1 (++)` is available in the standard library; it's called `concat`. `splitString` is available in the `text` library for the data type `Text` as `split (== '-')`, in the `MissingH` library as `split "-"`, in the `split` library as `splitWhen (== '-')`, or in the `bytestring` library for data type `ByteString` as `split (== '-')`.